# VBA date format code

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if there is any possibility to write a **VBA code** where the column A should always have a **date format**  like this: **12.10.2017** (not 12/10/2017 or 12-10-2017). If anything else is written in the column A like "**12**" or "**car**" the entry should be deleted. It has to accept only the date format mentioned above.

I used data validation for this, with length 10 and the date format to take only "." into consideration,  but I want to do it as a VBA code instead.

Thanks!

Comment: Please refer to [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You will need a worksheet_change event to check for user entries along with code to read the input and check against your rules. If rules met, do nothing, else .ClearContents on target cell. Normally, you would use the format options provided in the spreadsheet and as date can be a nightmare normally choose something unambiguous such as the international standard yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Set your rules up to exclude at the earliest possible point e..g If len <> 10, if count of "." not = 2, if any non numeric character present (ignoring ".")

Comment: @QHarr: will give a try now.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Select Case Target.Column     Case = 1 for column A etc..

Comment: Change the **NumberFormat** instead of forcing to separated by dots. Pleases everyone. If you need the value in that dots format, use the `RangeObject.Text` in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

A valid date is a long representing the number of days since the 1st january 1900. So a valid date would be 45603. You can display this date in any format you wish using the format codes d, m and y . So to display the date as dd.mm.yyyy then set that numberformat in the cells in column A.  Your problem though is that Excel will only accept a date entered as either a long or in a built in date format (using /, - or space as a separator). You could allow the users to enter a text string in the format dd.mm.yyyy and then convert that string into a date and then reject it if the conversion didn't result in a valid date - but wouldn't it be easier to just train your users to enter dates correctly?